# Specific image shows up locally but not on website (GitHub Pages)

Tags: html, github-pages

I pushed a new page (http://www.sethgibbs.xyz/music/track/all-tracks) to my website, and the rest of the images show up normally, but this one specific image (_logo.png) seems to be broken somehow. Ctrl-F to the 2018 section and you'll see it.

I committed the "img/cover" folder which contains the image, and if I check the repository I can see that it does indeed exist, right here: https://github.com/Alpha-Hedge/Alpha-Hedge.github.io/blob/master/music/img/cover/_logo.png

The image shows up correctly when looking at the page locally (opening the html file in my browser), but appears broken when using the online version.

The img tag in the code looks like this:

```
<img title="This track does not have its own cover art." src="../img/cover/_logo.png">
```

...and every other use of this image is the same exact line.
An example of an image that shows up correctly:

```
<img src="../img/cover/bismuth.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that start with underscores are omitted. Check this for a work around => https://help.github.com/en/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing

Comment: Ah, okay. Should've known it'd be something simple like that; changing the name seemed to fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing _ from the filename?